# Build a huffman tree using min-heap

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, heap, huffman-code

I came across some problems when building a huffman tree. When building the huffman tree, I use min-heap to implement. And I think the code of min-heap is work well, but when I run the building-huffman-Tree code, the error appears. I have dug into it for a long time, but I have no means to solve it.Hope someone help me sovle my problem.The code is following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 100
#define MaxData NULL

// Huffman tree的建树过程用最小堆时因为每次都可以挑出最小的两个元素组成

typedef struct TreeNode {
    int weight;
    struct TreeNode *left;
    struct TreeNode *right;
}HuffmanTree;

typedef struct HeapStruct {
    HuffmanTree *Elements[MaxSize+1];      // an array
    int Size;      // the number of item in array
    int Capacity;      /* the capacity of heap */
}MinHeap;



MinHeap *Create()
{   // create a empty heap
    MinHeap *H;
    H = (MinHeap *)malloc(sizeof(MinHeap));
    H->Elements[0] = NULL;
    H->Size = 0;
    H->Capacity = MaxSize;
    return H;
}

int isFull(MinHeap *H) 
{   // judge the heap full or not 
    return (H->Size == MaxSize);
}

int isEmpty(MinHeap *H)
{   // judge the heap empty or not
    return (H->Size == 0);
} 

void Add(MinHeap *H, int item)
{   // add item to the array
    if( isFull(H) )
    {
        printf("the heap is full.\n");
        return;
    }
    HuffmanTree *T;
    T = (HuffmanTree *)malloc(sizeof(HuffmanTree));
    T->weight = item;
    H->Elements[++(H->Size)] = T;
    return;
}

void Insert(MinHeap *H, HuffmanTree *item)
{   // insert item 
    int i;
    if( isFull(H) )
    {
        printf("the heap is full.\n");
        return;
    }
    i = ++(H->Size);
    for(; (H->Elements[i/2]->weight)>(item->weight);i/=2)
        H->Elements[i] = H->Elements[i/2];
    H->Elements[i] = item;
}

HuffmanTree *DeleteMin(MinHeap *H)
{   // delete item of the heap
    int Parent, Child;
    HuffmanTree *MinValueNode, *tempNode;
    if( isEmpty(H) )
    {
        printf("the heap is empty.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    MinValueNode = H->Elements[1];
    tempNode = H->Elements[H->Size--];
    for(Parent=1; Parent*2<=H->Size; Parent=Child)
    {
        Child = Parent * 2;
        if( (Child != H->Size) && (H->Elements[Child]->weight > H->Elements[Child+1]->weight) )
            Child++;
        if( tempNode->weight <= H->Elements[Child]->weight )
            break;
        else 
            H->Elements[Parent] = H->Elements[Child];
    } 
    H->Elements[Parent] = tempNode;
    return MinValueNode; 
}

void PercDown(MinHeap *H, int i)
{   // adjustment of the heap 
    int Parent, Child;
    HuffmanTree *temp;
    temp = H->Elements[i];
    for(Parent=i; Parent*2<=H->Size; Parent=Child)
    {
        Child = Parent * 2;
        if( (Child != H->Size) && (H->Elements[Child]->weight > H->Elements[Child+1]->weight) )
            Child++;      // Child point to the min 
        if( temp->weight <= H->Elements[Child]->weight )    
            break;
        else        
            H->Elements[Parent] = H->Elements[Child];      
    }
    H->Elements[Parent] = temp;
}

void BuildMinHeap(MinHeap *H)
{ 
    int i;
    for(i=H->Size/2; i>0; i--)
        PercDown(H, i);
    return;
}

HuffmanTree *Huffman(MinHeap *H)
{   /* Assuming that H->Size weight hava existed in H->Elements[]->weight */
    int i;
    HuffmanTree *T;

    BuildMinHeap( H );     // adjustment 
    for(i=1; i<H->Size; i++)      // merge H->Size-1  
    {
        T = (HuffmanTree *)malloc(sizeof(HuffmanTree));      
        T->left = DeleteMin( H );      
        T->right = DeleteMin( H );     
        T->weight = T->left->weight + T->right->weight;     
        Insert(H, T); 
    }
    T = DeleteMin( H );
    return T;
}

void print_heap(MinHeap *H)
{
    if( isEmpty(H) )
    {
        printf("the heap is empty.\n");
        return;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=H->Size; i++)
        printf("%d   ", H->Elements[i]->weight);
    printf("\n");
} 

void print_tree(HuffmanTree *T)
{
    if( T )
    {
        print_tree(T->left);
        printf("%d ", T->weight);
        print_tree(T->right);
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    MinHeap *heap;
    HuffmanTree *HT, *T;
    heap = Create();
    int x;
    printf("please input data:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    while( x )
    {
        Add(heap, x);
        scanf("%d", &x);
    }   
    printf("original items:\n");
    print_heap( heap );
    printf("the item number of heap%d\n", heap->Size);
    BuildMinHeap(heap);
    print_heap( heap );
    HT = DeleteMin( heap );
    printf("删除的结点的值为%d\n", HT->weight);
    print_heap( heap );
    HT = Huffman( heap );
    print_tree( HT );
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please provide some more details about the error you are seeing so we can better help you.

Comment: @RyanWalker    <code>HT = Huffman( heap );</code>   between the <code> label that is my C codes. I try to use “HT = Huffman( heap );” to build a huffman tree, but when I run my code , the “huffmanTree.exe” will say "stop to work". I am annoyed by it very much. So do you have any good solution to help me with it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ryan Walker Thank you.